# Javascript strange error

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, sorry of my poor english. Here is my JSfiddle, for my problem:

```
var x = 21;
var mod = x % 4;
switch (mod) {
    case 0:
        var z = x;
        break;
    case 1:
        var y = 3;
        var z = x + y;
        break;
    case 2:
        var y = 2;
        var z = x + y;
        break;
    case 3:
        var y = 1;
        var z = x + y;
        break;
}
console.log(z);
```

[jsfiddle.net/dsh0upyn/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/dsh0upyn/1/)

Why javascript give back result 351 instead of 36? If you uncomment "var x= 35;", and use it instead of second line, code works fine.

I cant understand, if the script can solve modulus, and use it as a number, but after it used as a  string and concatenate 35 and 1.

Comment: Please post your javascript code

Comment: post the code with fiddle.

Comment: When you posted the jsfiddle link, you got a notification saying you must include code. Please don't skate around requirements—they're there for a reason.

Comment: Use parseInt() for the value, it is read as string.

Comment: I get both time 351. So, you need to use parseInt()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse it with [`.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) because `+` is for the concatenation for sting values if you want to perform addition you need to parse it.

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("input-option").value , 10);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dsh0upyn/3/)

Comment: `parseInt("123", 10)`

Comment: @slash197 I know updating, providing base :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `.value` by default takes value as string, you need convert it to integer with `parseInt()`.

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("input-option").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here buddy,

```
   var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("input-option").value);
```

Is what you need

http://jsfiddle.net/dsh0upyn/4/

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `+` operator is for string concatenation - the value as you get it from input is a string. To use it as a number, change `x` to `1*x`:

http://jsfiddle.net/ndru/dsh0upyn/2/

Answer (score 0):

By default it is string ..do conversion

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("input-option").value);
```

Comment: Ok, i agree with that, but simply just cant understand, when it is basically string, how can solve mod = x % 4  without of using parseInt?

Comment: without `parseint` it ll perform like `"35" +1`..it concat So it produce 351

Comment: It's because you can use `+` operand for strings concatenation, but other mathematical operands such as `*,%, etc.` cannot be used for strings, so javascript automatically converts string to number.

Comment: So using type="number" in input filed seems to be meaninless?

Comment: @Peszo it is used to setting the element’s value to a string representing a number

Comment: `type="number"` is used for other purposes. By using number type you can assign min, max & step values for input. And it can be increased or decreased by arrows on input right.